# How to get kafka consumer-id for logging

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

In my application i'm using `spring-kafka` to consume message from kafka server, but from console consumer i get `consumer-id` of all consumer threads that are active

```
TOPIC            PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             CONSUMER-ID                                    HOST            CLIENT-ID
easytest-events    9          247367          247367          0             p3-S14-0-e6a1d3cb-8ab3-435f-9f53-5081a6e8f812 /10.66.56.129   p3-S14-0
```

Is there a way to get `consumer-id` through code so that i can compare them

Comment: `kafka-consumer-groups` maps to a Java class that you can programmatically call, if that is the question, but what are you trying to compare?

Comment: as of now i have 20 partition topic and 20 consumer threads (which is 10 pods and each pod with two consumers using spring kafka `setConcurrency(2`)) so i want to log each `consumer-id` so that i can verify them by describing consumer group in console @cricket_007

Comment: and this is out off topic but how do i verify 20 consumer threads are created ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Spring, but I would guess JMX monitoring would help with that. Sounds like you have k8s, so getting Prometheus hooked into that is usually what people do, I guess

Answer (score 3):

The consumer-id appears to be the client-id appended with a UUID - so you can just use the client-id (which you can set to whatever you want). Spring will add -0, -1, etc.

You can see the number of threads in the logs as partitions are assigned...

```
2018-08-31 09:34:27.869  INFO 55748 --- [o52105744-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions assigned: [so52105744-0]
2018-08-31 09:34:27.876  INFO 55748 --- [o52105744-2-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions assigned: [so52105744-3]
2018-08-31 09:34:27.876  INFO 55748 --- [o52105744-1-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions assigned: [so52105744-2]
2018-08-31 09:34:27.876  INFO 55748 --- [o52105744-9-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions assigned: [so52105744-1]
2018-08-31 09:34:27.876  INFO 55748 --- [o52105744-3-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions assigned: [so52105744-4]
2018-08-31 09:34:27.876  INFO 55748 --- [o52105744-6-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions assigned: [so52105744-7]
2018-08-31 09:34:27.876  INFO 55748 --- [o52105744-5-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions assigned: [so52105744-6]
2018-08-31 09:34:27.876  INFO 55748 --- [o52105744-4-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions assigned: [so52105744-5]
2018-08-31 09:34:27.877  INFO 55748 --- [o52105744-7-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions assigned: [so52105744-8]
2018-08-31 09:34:27.877  INFO 55748 --- [o52105744-8-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions assigned: [so52105744-9]
```

Comment: but i n my case, i have two datacenters with 5 pods each ,and each pod has 2 consumers threads so spring is appending 0 to client id for one datacenter and 1 two another one, so i want to log all these consumer threads (which has uuid) so that i can easily find out only one pod threads are assigned remaining or sitting ideally @Gray Russell

Comment: Then I think you would have to use a different client-id on each datacenter/instance; I don't think the consumer-id is available at the client (at least I didn't find it in the api); I looked at the `metrics()` on the consumer and all that contains is the client-id.

Comment: i have no idea how to do that (each datacenter/instance), is there anyway to check spring kafka creates 2 consumers on each pod when i use this property `setConcurrency(2))`

Comment: `spring.kafka.client-id=${client.id}` then add a system property `-Dclient.id=datacenter1-pod1`. Why do you need to check the consumers? Spring will always start the configured number. If there are not enough partitions, some consumers will be idle. You can add a `ConsumerRebalanceListener` to the `ContainerProperties` to get a notification when partitions are assigned.

Comment: i'm little struck at this point, i will list out my problems please help me if you can? 1) i have 10 pods with 2 consumers in each pod for topic with 20 partitions, 2) so according to my knowledge each partitions should be consumed with each consumer, 3) in kubectl i can see all pods are running, 4) But when i describe consumer group i can see 8 consumers are running and assigned to multiple partitions, 5) how to find all consumers in consumer group including idle ones, 6) How to find weather spring create 20 are not, 7) why rebalancing is not happening ?

Comment: As I said in my original answer you can see partition assignment in INFO logs.

Comment: Okay, any idea why rebalancing is not happening? I want one consumer per partition, can i achieve this

Comment: It's hard to say; I've never seen anything like that; whenever I bring up multiple instances I see a rebalance every time. Maybe turning on debugging for `org.apache.kafka` might help. But it's nothing to do with Spring, and I don't have a clue what the problem might be.

Answer (score 2):

I also had the similar use case where I wanted to get the consumer Id for logging so I used the **current thread name** and it seems to work fine.

```
LOGGER.info("Current thread: {}",Thread.currentThread().getName());
```

and this prints:-

```
Current thread: org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1
Current thread: org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-2-C-1
Current thread: org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-1-C-1
```

this also shows clearly that the messages are being consumed each time by different thread(may be in the round-robin fashion)