# How to get consumer-id using a @KafkaListener spring boot 2 consumer

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

[image: Consumers listed using bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh utility]

```
bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe --group my-consumer
```

Is it possible to get `consumer-id` information like in above command output in a `Spring boot @KafkaListener consumer` ?
I want to add this the consumer-id to a table to represent a processor that processed data.
I have gone through @gary-russell's answer on [How to get kafka consumer-id for logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52105744/how-to-get-kafka-consumer-id-for-logging), But I dont see consumer-id appearing in partitions assigned logs.

```
[org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] INFO  o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer.info - my-consumer: partitions assigned: [test_topic-7, test_topic-6, test_topic-5, test_topic-4]
[org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#1-0-C-1] INFO  o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer.info - my-consumer: partitions assigned: [test_topic-3, test_topic-2, test_topic-1, test_topic-0]
```

I am using spring boot 2.2.2
dependencies: spring-kafka

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the `consumer-id` is available on the client; you can get the `client-id`s from the `metrics`:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So61616543Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So61616543Application.class, args).close();
    }


    @KafkaListener(id = "so61616543", topics = "so61616543")
    public void listen(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so61616543").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }


    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry registry) {
        return args -> {
            registry.getListenerContainer("so61616543").metrics()
                .forEach((clientId, metrics) -> {
                    System.out.println(clientId);
                    metrics.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println(key + ":" + value));
                });
        };
    }

}
```

Comment: When client.id used:    
`onJoinComplete [Consumer clientId=amber-0, groupId=sample-group-id]     
onJoinComplete - [Consumer clientId=amber-0, groupId=sample-group-id]      `

**Getting same Consumer clientId for both consumers.**    

When client.id is not used:    

`onJoinComplete - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=top-creatives-consumer] Setting newly assigned partitions: ...    
onJoinComplete - [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=top-creatives-consumer] Setting newly assigned partitions...    `

**Getting different Consumer clientId**
I did not quite follow this.

Comment: If you have two or more `@KafkaListener`s, then you need to set the `clientIdPrefix` on the `@KafkaListener` to override the consumer factory setting. Otherwise they will both get the same id.

Comment: I have multiple @KafkaListener's. I want them to be part of same group-id, but I want to log their different consumer client-id's. (processing from different partitions). Irrespective of if I set "client.id" or not both containers are processing correctly from different partitions in different threads. I dont get why consumer client-id are getting logged differently.

Comment: Because, as I said, you need to set the `clientIdPrefix` on the `@KafkaListener` annotations to get a different one for each. But, why do you need multiple listeners anyway? If they are all consuming from the same topic, simply set the `concurrency` to however many consumers you want to use. They will each get a unique client id.

Comment: :) I did not know about concurrency. Also I am getting client-id using above metrics example.

Comment: have u tried Nikolas Charalambidis answer and it worked for you? Amber Kulkarni ?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use the following chain of methods using autowired [`AdminClient`](https://kafka.apache.org/22/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/AdminClient.html):

```
public Collection<MemberDescription> members() 
    throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, TimeoutException 
{
  String group = "my-consumer";
  List<String> groups = Collections.singletonList(group);

  return adminClient
    .describeConsumerGroups(groups) // DescribeConsumerGroupsResult
    .describedGroups()              // Map<String, KafkaFuture<ConsumerGroupDescription>>
    .get(group)                     // KafkaFuture<ConsumerGroupDescription>
    .get(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)       // ConsumerGroupDescription
    .members();                     // Collection<MemberDescription>
}
```

The returned collection of the [`MemberDescription`](https://kafka.apache.org/22/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/MemberDescription.html) contains your consumers. The object provides the following "getters":

- [`MemberDescription::clientId`](https://kafka.apache.org/22/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/MemberDescription.html#clientId--) with the `CLIENT-ID` entries.
- [`MemberDescription::consumerId`](https://kafka.apache.org/22/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/MemberDescription.html#consumerId--) with the `COMSUMER-ID` entries.

The reason behind `KafkaFuture` wrapping is to support the asynchronous programming style in the Java-8 way implementing `java.util.concurrent.Future<T>`. You can either block a call with a hope for the result (should be available that time) using (`.get(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)`) or use the proper asynchronous way through Java-8 Futures.